# Pyqt - get CSV from model

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt

I have treeview based on proxymodel based on model.
So I get a table, that can be filtered and sortered.

I just want to export current view of this table to CSV file.
Just what I see, export to a file or print.

I suppose I have to use proxymodel for that, right?
I cant find a method row or something like that.

Really I have to use methods data(), rowCount() and collumnCount()?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any CSV parser or exporter for QAbstractItemModels, so I think you have to write your own exporting code, like this (pythonish pseudo-code):

```
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    for col in range(model.columnCount()):
        value = model.index( row, col, QModelIndex() ).data( Qt.DisplayRole ).toString()
        #write v, add separator...
    #finish row...
```

Using only generic QAbstractItemModel API it works for all models, proxy or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a CSV reader/writer for python, which you can use in [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld)'s solution.

See http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples for more examples!

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("some.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerows(someiterable)
```